# why function needs as argument tuple (last argument is empty ending with comma) when it was mentioned to use int

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning multiprocessing module. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) are examples where function calling is strange at least for me. Passing the arguments ends with comma (seems like last argument is empty or forgotten or something weird) e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,))    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
```

Or this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10,])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
```

Or this, where calling is done using named arguments

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

There are also examples where passing argument is done "classic" `(arg1,arg2)` way, I've tried modify above examples and delete the last comma but I gen an error. First I was thinking that those missed arguments are used with `Process` class and those "classic" arguments are used with `Pool` but there are exception on mentioned site.  <s>What does this convention mean? What is difference between `(arg1,)` and `(arg1)`?</s>

**EDIT**
 As it was mentioned in the comments `type((1,))` returns tuple where `type((1))` returns int. But `f(x)` function requires tuple?

Comment: `(foo)` is just foo , whereas `(foo,)` is a tuple of one element

Comment: Try ``type((1,))`` and you'll see, it's a tuple as ``type((1))``is an integer.

Comment: OK but why `f(x)` requires tuple?

Comment: It doesn't; `f(10)` works fine *if you want to call it right now*. However `Process` requires `args` to be a tuple, however many arguments you're supplying.

Comment: OK so is there any reason why `Process` requires tuple?